# How to display a dropdown field __str__ in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, forms, templates

I've got a ModelForm where I can display either a foreignkey field which comes as a dropdown list (`{{ form.auto_part }}`) or the `value` or the ID of that foreignkey field which comes as a number (`{{ form.auto_part.value }}`). But I want to show the `__str__` value of the foreignkey field. How can I do that?

**forms.py**

```
class AddCostPriceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['auto_part', 'cost_price']
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(Timestamped):
    product_list = models.ForeignKey(List)
    auto_part = models.ForeignKey(AutoPart)

    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='pcs')

    cost_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class AutoPart(Timestamped):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    auto_type = models.ForeignKey(AutoType)
    part_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{brand} {auto_type} - {part_no}".format(brand=self.brand, auto_type=self.auto_type, part_no=self.part_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ModelChoiceField should allow you to do this, it is the default behavior. You can configure the labels.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Example:

```
class AddCostPriceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    auto_part = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=AutoPart.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['auto_part', 'cost_price']
```

Comment: Can you please give an example?